# Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password). in git

Tags: git

I have installed windows 7 on my pc after windows xp and I am setting up git again, I have sent pub file to admin and he has updated my pub file.

Then also I am getting following issue

```
git pull origin master
git@19.2.2.2's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
git@19.2.2.2's password:
Permission denied, please try again.
git@19.2.2.2's password:
Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

> Please make sure you have the correct access rights
>   and the repository exists.

I am not able to do a basic git pull or git clone now.
The admin says he has done all necessary work.

What could the issue be?

Comment: Have you configured your SSH settings?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: SSL generally has nothing to do with SSH.

Comment: Whats is the repo url? http? https? ssh?

Comment: For me it looks like your pub key was not registered properly. The remote asked for the `git` users password not for your ssh-pubkey password.

Comment: @codeWizard  repo is ssh

Comment: And what is your central repo? github? gitlab? stash?

Comment: On Windows it is not enough to have generated files in your %HOME%\.ssh directory. Look from where git reads the key. http://guides.beanstalkapp.com/version-control/git-on-windows.html Chapter Having problems connecting to your Git repository on Windows 7?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Either the admin hadn't registered your public key properly, or your own public key is not defined in the correct location as git expects.

Make sure your key is generated by the `ssh-keygen` command available in your Git Bash.